# Create an email body in HTML that includes information from an object

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I have a VBA object, `aPosition`.
I am trying to display information `aPosition.something` in an email.

My code gives me a syntax error.

```
strBody = "<HTML>" strBody & "<BR> & <p style='font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;font-size:22'>Equity position in sell: " & aPosition.SEC_NAME & " (" & aPosition.ISIN & ")" & " now in "& aPosition._RANKING" </p> & _
                 " Target Price: " & aPosition.TARGET_PRICE & "<BR>" & _
                 "<b><span style=""color:#C00000"">We have downgraded</span style=""color:#C00000""></b>" & aPosition.SEC_NAME & "<BR>" & " <U>Clients Impacted:</U><BR>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems when building your string.

First of all, you can use single quotes in your styles to eliminate the possible double-double quotes confusion.

Secondly, you seem to have `strBody` mixed in there twice for some reason.

Also, whatever `aPosition` is, you cannot have a property that starts with an underscore (`aPosition._Ranking` not valid), so I removed just that underscore. (so double check that part)

Try it like this:

```
strBody = "<HTML>" & strBody & "<BR><p style='font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;font-size:22'>Equity position in sell: " & aPosition.SEC_NAME & " (" & aPosition.ISIN & ") now in " & aPosition.RANKING & "</p>" & _
                 " Target Price: " & aPosition.TARGET_PRICE & "<BR>" & _
                 "<b><span style='color:#C00000'>We have downgraded</span style='color:#C00000'></b>" & aPosition.SEC_NAME & "<BR><U>Clients Impacted:</U><BR>"
```

Comment: it tooks time to me to answer but you solution worked nice ! Indeed, the bigger problem was coming from the quotes and the use of the object. When displaying object in your code, always do like this " & My_object.my_prop & " within the string. Thanks and sorry again for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is to make sure you set a well-formed HTML markup to the HTMLBody property, for example, I see the following:

```
strBody = "<HTML>" strBody & "<BR>
```

If you want to modify the existing email body you need to paste your HTML pieces after the `<body>` tag and before the closing `</body>` tag.